# Query help need in finding missing numbers

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ID         | GROUP
-------------------
1000001    | 0
1000001    | 1
1000001    | 2
1000002    | 0
1000002    | 2
1000002    | 3
1000003    | 1
1000003    | 2
1000003    | 3
1000004    | 0
```

I need to list all the ids where there is a group missing in the sequence.
So for the above example i would only need back 1000002 & 1000003.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you can (maybe also should) solve in a DBMS, but maybe I don't know oracle well enough^^

Comment: Do you mean, return all IDs, for which there is some Group k+1 but no Group k, k>0?

Comment: i meant where there is some group k+1 but no group k and also if group 0 is missing@maxstar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct id
from
(
    SELECT Id, Group, LAG(Group, 1, -1) over (partition by Id order by Group) prevGroup
 FROM Table
 )     
 WHERe Group -1 <> PrevGroup
```

Comment: Wow, looking at this answer makes me feel like I don't know SQL at all.  :)  I have no idea what LAG or partition are or how they'd be used.

Comment: @XstreamINsanity, LAG provides access to more than one row of a table at the same time without a self-join. Given a series of rows returned from a query and a position of the cursor, LAG provides access to a row at a given physical offset prior to that position.
Look to http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html

Comment: in your defense, it's pretty new-ish.  I think the Oracle analytics first came out when 9i did, and even theyn they were only in Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 2):

As we don need the information about the missing group number we can compare that over all count of elements is lower or equal for specific group

```
SELECT ID FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING COUNT(ID) <= max(GROUP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM mytable m
GROUP BY id
HAVING (MAX(group) + 1) > COUNT(DISTINCT group);
```

(I've written the keys in lowercase). If you have a unique key on `(ID, GROUP)`, you can leave out the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: may be need 'group by id', not a 'group by group'?

Comment: @XstreamINsanity, Correct query is SELECT distinct id from table GROUP BY id HAVING MAX(group) + 1 > (COUNT(DISTINCT group));

Comment: @Michael: you're absolutely right (both times). I posted this answer a bit too quick.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm getting from your comments is that the ID must start with a group of 0 and the group should always increment only by 1.  From that, I get this:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
        SELECT  id, count(*) as cnt, max(group) as mx, min(group) as mn
        FROM    myTable
        GROUP BY group
     ) A
WHERE NOT mx = cnt - 1
AND NOT mn = 0
```

Hope this helps.  It's probably not the cleanest or most effective, but hope it will help.

EDIT:  Actually, after re-looking over the answer before mine and thinking about HAVING, it probably would be cleaner like this.

```
SELECT ID
FROM   myTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MAX(group) >= COUNT(DISTINCT group)
```